# Как переключать между тегами и забрать текст с таблицы BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Как забрать весь текст с `td` и переключатся по тегам?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.us-proxy.org/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
trs = soup.find('table', id = 'proxylisttable').find_all('tbody')#.find_all('td')
print(trs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `css-селектор` удобнее составлять запросы:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rs = requests.get('https://www.us-proxy.org/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'lxml')

for tr in soup.select('#proxylisttable > tbody > tr'):
    td_list = [td.text for td in tr.select('td')]
    print(td_list)
```

Консоль:

```
['45.76.175.214', '3128', 'US', 'United States', 'elite proxy', 'no', 'yes', '19 seconds ago']
['52.179.97.251', '3128', 'US', 'United States', 'anonymous', 'no', 'yes', '10 minutes ago']
['47.88.32.46', '3128', 'US', 'United States', 'anonymous', 'no', 'no', '10 minutes ago']
['52.183.36.137', '80', 'US', 'United States', 'elite proxy', 'no', 'no', '11 minutes ago']
['66.82.144.29', '8080', 'US', 'United States', 'elite proxy', 'no', 'no', '30 minutes ago']
['40.87.66.157', '80', 'US', 'United States', 'elite proxy', 'no', 'no', '30 minutes ago']
...
```

Comment: @Sasha294, а чем мой ответ вас не устроил?